# Reshape data within groups - groups in a single row

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

This is my input data :

```
 DeviceID   ContentID   Use
 D1 C1  0.678491346
 D1 C2  0.302147374
 D2 C1  0.695790066
 D2 C2  0.645849165
 D3 C1  0.83503997
 D3 C2  0.3622916
```

The expected output :

```
DeviceID    ContentID_1 Use_1   ContentID_2 Use_2
D1  C1  0.678491346 C2  0.302147374
D2  C1  0.695790066 C2  0.645849165
D3  C1  0.83503997  C2  0.3622916
```

I tried to reshape it using reshape2, but wasn't able to get it in the required format.

I tried :

```
 df %>% 
   group_by(DeviceID) %>% 
   mutate(rn = paste0("Content",row_number())) %>% 
   spread(rn, Use)
```

and

```
dcast(df,
      DeviceID~ContentID,
      value.var ="Use")
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How did you try it?

Comment: `dcast(df,Device ID~Content ID, value.var ="Use")`. But I get the Content Id as columns.

Comment: But I was clueless on how to get the Content ID as a row

Comment: Please add this attempt to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my solution to this:

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(DeviceId) %>%
  summarise_all(function(x) paste0(x, collapse = "_")) %>%
  cSplit(names(.)[-1], '_')
```

Including the suggestion from @AntoniosK in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

we can use `Reduce` and `aggregate` to rearrange it in the format given above

```
data.frame(Reduce(cbind,aggregate(.~Device,dat,I)))[c(1,2,4,3,5)]
  init V2          V4 V3          V5
1   D1 C1 0.678491346 C2 0.302147374
2   D2 C1 0.695790066 C2 0.645849165
3   D3 C1  0.83503997 C2   0.3622916
```

This is a brute force of library dplyr

```
 map2_dfc(s<-dat%>%spread(Id,Content),names(s),~rev(stack(s,.y)))
     ind values ind1   values1 ind2   values2
1 Device     D1   C1 0.6784913   C2 0.3021474
2 Device     D2   C1 0.6957901   C2 0.6458492
3 Device     D3   C1 0.8350400   C2 0.3622916
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do this using dplyr/reshape2?

Comment: I cannot think of any right now. But if there is, one will post it here.

Comment: Could you explain `aggregate(.~Device,dat,I)`?

Comment: `aggregate` takes in data and groups it with respect to the provided factor then performs the function on the grouped data. my function is the `I ` (identity) function. essentially just dividing the data but outputting that same data

Comment: eg try `aggregate(.~Species,iris,mean)`

Answer (score 2):

As of v1.9.6 (on CRAN 19 Sep 2015), `data.table` can cast multiple value columns simultaneously:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), DeviceID ~ rowid(DeviceID), value.var = c("ContentID", "Use"))
```

> ```
>     DeviceID  ContentID_1  ContentID_2     Use_1     Use_2
> 1:        D1           C1           C2 0.6784913 0.3021474
> 2:        D2           C1           C2 0.6957901 0.6458492
> 3:        D3           C1           C2 0.8350400 0.3622916
> ```

#### Changing column order

The result contains the expected columns but in a different order. `dcast()` creates the new columns grouped by `value.var`.

The OP has not indicated whether the exact column order is of importance or not. However, the expected result can be reproduced exactly by changing the column order *by reference*, i.e., without copying the whole data object using `setcolorder()`:

```
cols <- c("ContentID", "Use")
wide <- dcast(setDT(df), DeviceID ~ rowid(DeviceID), value.var = cols)
new_col_order <- CJ(seq_len(uniqueN(df$ContentID)), cols)[, paste(V2, V1, sep = "_")]
setcolorder(wide, new_col_order)
wide
```

> ```
>    ContentID_1     Use_1 ContentID_2     Use_2 DeviceID
> 1:          C1 0.6784913          C2 0.3021474       D1
> 2:          C1 0.6957901          C2 0.6458492       D2
> 3:          C1 0.8350400          C2 0.3622916       D3
> ```

`CJ()` is a cross join of the row ids with the value.vars to create the column names in the desired order.

I have filed a [feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2601) to optionally change the order of columns in `dcast()`.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread(
  " DeviceID  ContentID  Use
 D1 C1  0.678491346
  D1 C2  0.302147374
  D2 C1  0.695790066
  D2 C2  0.645849165
  D3 C1  0.83503997
  D3 C2  0.3622916"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = read.table(text = "
DeviceId  ContentID  Use
D1 C1  0.678491346
D1 C2  0.302147374
D2 C1  0.695790066
D2 C2  0.645849165
D3 C1  0.83503997
D3 C2  0.3622916
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(DeviceId) %>%
  summarise_all(function(x) paste0(x, collapse = "_")) %>%
  separate(ContentID, c("ID_1","ID_2"), sep="_") %>%
  separate(Use, c("Use_1","Use_2"), sep="_")

# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#   DeviceId ID_1  ID_2  Use_1       Use_2      
# * <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>       <chr>      
# 1 D1       C1    C2    0.678491346 0.302147374
# 2 D2       C1    C2    0.695790066 0.645849165
# 3 D3       C1    C2    0.83503997  0.3622916
```

Comment: If I gave more than 2 categories? My actual data has n number of categories, is there a way to make the `into` argument in `separate` dynamic?

Comment: I wish there was a `separate_all` function :-) You'll probably have to create your own function or use a different package. I'll have a look.

Comment: `df %>%
  group_by(DeviceId) %>%
  summarise_all(function(x) paste0(x, collapse = "_")) %>%
  cSplit(c('ContentID', 'Use'), '_')`

using `cSplit' from the `splitstackshape` package


Thank you @AntoniosK for setting me in the right direction!

Comment: Great! Or maybe `cSplit(names(.)[-1], '_')` if you want to automatically exclude first column, without typing all column names of interest...

Comment: That is a neat trick!

Comment: Also keep in mind that within `summarise_all` you can use the `funs()` argument, like this `summarise_all(funs(paste0(., collapse = "_")))`. This will give you the same result. However, `funs()` can be used to apply multiple functions to multiple columns, like this: `summarise_all(funs(a = paste0(., collapse = "_"),
                     b = paste0(., collapse = "||")))` which might be really useful in a different case in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
DT <- setDT(df)
```

Using your dcast intent, you could do

```
    Reduce(function(dtf1,dtf2) merge(dtf1,dtf2, by = "DeviceId"), 
           lapply( unique(DT$ContentID),
                   function(x){dcast(DT[ContentID == x],DeviceId + ContentID  ~ ContentID ,value.var = "Use")} ))

   DeviceId ContentID.x        C1 ContentID.y        C2
1:       D1          C1 0.6784913          C2 0.3021474
2:       D2          C1 0.6957901          C2 0.6458492
3:       D3          C1 0.8350400          C2 0.3622916
```